# How to query DBPedia from JavaScript by resource URI?

Tags: javascript, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I try to make this query from JavaScript

```
        var subject = document.getElementById("inputUri").value;
        var property = "?p";
        var object = "?o";
        var query = "\
        PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>\
        PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>\
        PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>\
        SELECT *    \
        WHERE {\
            "+ subject + property + object +".\
        }LIMIT 10";
```

And I receive the variable ?s from an input form, but when I write another variable name, it doesn't work. 
The code for the result is the following:

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: "jsonp",  
            url: queryUrl,
            success: function( _data ) {
                var results = _data.results.bindings;
                var subject = document.getElementById("inputUri").value;
                for ( var i in results ) {
                    var subjectResult = results[i].s.value;
                    var objectResult = results[i].o.value;
                    var propertyResult = results[i].p.value;
                } 
            }
        });
```

In

```
var subjectResult = results[i].s.value;
```

Is the error, but I don't know to receive the value from my input text to the subjectResult assignation.

---

I defined the variable which receives any variable name from the input text, by this way:

```
var str = subject;
var res = str.replace("?", "");
```

Then in the for loop:

```
var subjectResult = results[i][res].value;
```

Comment: Copy and paste error as usual. You took a query from somewhere and code from somewhere else without understanding it. Your subject is not a variable `?s` but bound to a specific resource URI - as your question title also implies.

Answer (score 1):

There is no variable called `?s` in your query, so it makes sense you can't retrieve its value.

Depending on the structure of your code, you should be able to use the `subject` variable directly:

```
var subjectResult = subject;
var objectResult = results[i].o.value;
var propertyResult = results[i].p.value;
```

Another option is to create the variable in your query, using `BIND`:

```
"SELECT *\
WHERE {\
    BIND(" + subject + " AS ?s)\
    ?s ?p ?o .\
} LIMIT 10"
```

Not sure what SPARQL server are you using, but when I tried this on Virtuoso, it failed with a confusing error, even though I believe it's valid SPARQL.

Also note that building queries like this from user input leaves you open to injection attacks.